# Select rectangle and delete surrounding areas

Tags: paint.net

I am new to Paint.Net.  When I select a rectangle (Tools -> Rectangle Select), I would like to delete all the areas outside of the rectangle.  How can I do this?

(Currently, I copy the selected rectangle, then to Edit->Paste in to New Image.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to blank out the area outside the selection press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (to invert the selection) and then <kbd>Del</kbd>.

However, since you're pasting the selection as a new image looks like what you really want to do is **crop to selection**, which you can accomplish by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> after selecting the area you want to retain.

Comment: +1 and marked as answer.  Thank you so much.  (You read my mind in terms of my ultimate goal.)

Answer (score 4):

Select the rectangular area you want to keep, then select Edit->Invert Selection.  You can then act on that selection, including deleting it by Edit->Erase Selection.